# Alternative to HTML5 block-level anchors

Tags: css, html

I searched a lot on alternatives for block-level anchors. HTML 5 allows a `<a>` tag around a block element, but some software like `CKEditor` (used in GetSimple, for example) won't support that:

```
<a href="myLinkTarget">
  <div>
    <h2>Great feature</h2>
    <p>One new and exciting thing you can
    do in HTML 5 is wrap links round “block-level” elements.</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

How do you make an HTML block element act as hyperlink, if block-level anchors for some reason ain't available and JavaScript should be avoided?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a block container for the content - and then put an absoluely positioned `<a>` element above this content to provide the hyperlink. Use CSS to display the `<a>` as block and stretch it to the parental container (Demo/JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhfegLft/1/).

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <h2>Block content</h2>
  <p>Even more content</p>
  <!-- Think about screen readers, give the hyperlink some content -->
  <a class="boxlink" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Visit Stackoverflow</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
}
.box a.boxlink {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #0000FF;
}
.box a.boxlink:hover {
    border-color: #FF9900;
}
```

Cool, because: No width or height definition is required.

**Limitations**

1. You can style the overlay block on hover (e.g., border, transparent background), but not the contents of the container, as "real" block-level anchors would have allowed.
2. The container/box must not be `position: static`.
3. The content of the underlying box is not selectable or otherwise available for user-interactions (e.g. JavaScript).

Comment: Additional Limitation, the underlying content will not be selectable.